# Можно ли получить доступ ко View MenuItem в ActionBar?

Tags: android, actionbar

Мне нужно задать свойство значка в меню экшн-бара, а именно focusable в false.
Никак не могу подобраться к View этого значка.

Когда я энкоредом, который прикидывается клавиатурой с кнопками вверх-вниз-ввод, веду вверх, я хочу, чтобы фокус получало только стрелка назад (home button), а не другие значки.

Comment: Получить элемент из MenuItem можно в onPrepareOptionsMenu.

Comment: Спасибо. Но у MenuItem нет свойства focusable. Мне нужен View

Comment: @AndreyMihalev Может я что-то не так понял. У вашего `ActionBar` есть лейаут `menu.xml` в котором вы определяете итемы и их свойства? Берете из этого лейаута id значков которые вам нужны и делаете  `findViewByID(R.id.myItem).setFocusable(false)`

Comment: @Eugene покажите разметку этого View

Comment: @Danilka37, если бы всё было так просто, но вот это вернёт null findViewByID(R.id.myItem), а это findViewByID(R.id.myItem).setFocusable(false) NPE соответственно.

Comment: С рефлексией тоже не получится, поля focusable нет даже приватного, нечего менять. Пока что у меня есть только один вариант - создать свой FocusableMenuItem на основе смеси View и MenuItem (а точнее SupportMenuItem), но у меня не получается, т.к. у них метод setContentDescription "clashes" из-за разных типов возвращаемых значений.

Comment: Если вы посредством клавиатуры пробегаете по экрану, то у вас просто не получиться выключить focusable для каких-то конкретных кнопок. Это противоестественно android. Даже, если вам удасться обогнуть данный UI, то скорее всего вы так же не сможете на них нажать. Вообще, предлагаю вам поточнее развернуть ваш вопрос, чтобы мы могли придумать решение, аналогичное по функциональности.

Comment: @Георгий Чеботарев Вот мне и нужно сделать противоестественно, чтобы стрелками на клавиатуре было невозможно на них навести курсор. У меня прибор, где в принципе непонятно, что на нём работает Android.

Answer (score 4):

Объявите переменную `MenuItem` до метода `onCreate`;

```
private MenuItem itemAction;
```

Затем в методе `onCreateOptionsMenu` получите ссылки на нужные вам кнопки в `ActionBar'e`;

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    // Получаем ссылку
    itemAction = menu.findItem(R.id.item_action)
    return true;
}
```

И в нужном месте делайте эту кнопку неактивной:

```
itemAction.setEnabled(false);
```

Или и вовсе скрывайте:

```
itemAction.setVisible(false);
```

Comment: Я и так легко могу делать MenuItem неактивным или скрытым, у MenuItem есть такие свойства. Повторюсь, мне нужно свойство focusable. Оно есть у View и его наследников, но нет у MenuItem.

Comment: Каким образом вы можете делать их неактивными за пределами `onOptionsItemSelected`? Ну вы сами говорите что его нет, а потом спрашиваете как его вызвать, где логика?

Comment: Задача в том, что мне нужно, чтобы курсор обходил меню, перепрыгивал. И то, что нет такого свойства как focusable, является препятствием к осуществлению задачи. За препятствиями в разработке, вроде как, и обращаются на stackoverflow.

Comment: @Eugene этот ответ как раз позволяет подобраться к View напрямую, вы пробовали использовать этот пример в своем коде? Если ответ не является решением - покажите ваш код и разметку!

Comment: Это надо заново писать. Но я пробовал. Если сделать findViewById Будет NPE, а этот findItem мне мало полезен.

Comment: Конечно будет NPE, потому что ссылку на айтемы меню получают через findItem, возможно вы просто не поняли данный ответ.

Comment: Я понял, но это не решает моей задачи.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, способ найден. Нужно в меню засетить свой кастомный View. Например, картинку или даже целый слой. В menu.xml у view добавляется свойство actionViewClass="ImageView", в коде при создании menu нужно вручную создать и засеттить в меню нужную вьюшку с помощью метода menu.setActionView(view). В итоге получаем в меню обычный View, а с ним и контролируемое свойство focusable.

Comment: а еще проще заюзать `Toolbar` и внутри него разместить свою вью

Comment: Так я и использую Toolbar. А вы что думали?